# Python Random Map Generation with Perlin Noise

Tags: python, random, perlin-noise

Recently, I've been attempting to defeat one of my main weaknesses in programming in general, random generation.  I thought it would be an easy thing to do, but the lack of simple information is killing me on it.  I don't want to sound dumb, but it feels to me like most of the information from places like [this](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm) are written for mathematicians who went to college to graduate in theoretical mathematics.  I just don't understand what I'm meant to do with that information in order to apply it to programming in a language such as python.

I've been working a few days staring at equations and attempting attempt after attempt, but still after all those days, after ripping my code apart again and again, all that's been working properly this entire time is this noise generator to generate basic noise:

```
import random
import math

random.seed(0)

def generateWhiteNoise(width,height):
    noise = [[r for r in range(width)] for i in range(height)]

    for i in range(0,height):
        for j in range(0,width):
            noise[i][j] = random.randint(0,1)

    return noise

noise = generateWhiteNoise(50,12)

for i in noise:
    print()
    for o in i:
        if(o == 0):
            print('-',end='')
        else:
            print('#',end='')
```

This code produces this result:

```
##-######--#--#-#--##-###-###---#-##-#-----#--##-#
#-#-##-##-#----##------##--#####-#-##---#--#-##---
-------#-#------#---#-#---###--#--#-###-----##-#--
######--#-#-#--####-###---#---###-##--#-#-##--####
-#----###--------##--##--##-#-#--#----###-####--##
---####-#--#--###-#-#--#--#####--####-#-##-##--#--
----#--####-#-#-#-#-#---#--###------###--#-######-
--###--#-###-------#-##--###---#-####----###-#####
#----##--##-#--##-###--#----#-#-##--##-#-##---###-
##---##----##--##--#--#--###-###-#--#-##---#------
-##----#-###---######---#-#---#---###---#---###-##
#--##-##-###-###---#--##-##--##-##-#-#-##--#-#-##-
```

I'm wanting it to eventually produce something like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------
------------------####----------------------------
-----------------#####----------------------------
----------------#####-----------------------------
---------------#####--------------###-------------
---------------#####--------------###-------------
---------------------------------####-------------
---######------------------------####-------------
---######------------###--------------------------
----########---------###--------------------------
-----#######---------###--------------------------
------###-----------------------------------------
```

How can I manage to smooth out the white-noise I generate, and turn it into islands?  Can anyone explain it in a very simplistic way for me?

I may be thinking about all of this very wrong.

Comment: I would take user1483482's suggestion.  If you want to know more about the inner workings try looking here: http://devmag.org.za/2009/04/25/perlin-noise/

I reproduced his code in python, and it works, but it is **very** slow, even with numpy.

Answer (score 10):

The direct answer to your question is "No, you cannot do what you are asking", and the second answer is "Yes, you are thinking about this all wrong".

The reason is that you are generating completely random noise. What you are asking for is coherent noise. They are two completely different animals and you cannot get coherent noise from random noise. Hence my answer.

To explain why, you must understand this simple statement which I am repeating from the [excellent libnoise documentation](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/glossary/index.html#coherentnoise):

---

## **Coherent noise**

*A type of smooth pseudorandom noise.*

Coherent noise is generated by a coherent-noise function, which has three important properties:

- Passing in the same input value will always return the same output value.
- A small change in the input value will produce a small change in the output value.
- A large change in the input value will produce a random change in the output value.

---

Random noise does not have these properties, and therefore is completely unsuitable for what you are trying to achieve.

I would suggest studying [Ken Perlin's latest (improved) reference implementation](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/noise/) and his [SIGGRAPH 2002](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/paper445.pdf) notes.

If you cannot understand or implement this, then just use a library such as [libnoise](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/), an excellent and well used LGPL library originally in C++ which has also been ported to many other languages.

Comment: "you cannot get coherent noise from random noise" - you can do that, in multiple ways. The most primitive is to average nearby values. Perlin Noise is famous way to get coherent noise from random noise.

Comment: "you cannot get coherent noise from random noise" Of course you can

Comment: No, coherent noise comes from pseudorandom noise. Random noise does not have an input property which when supplied always provides identical output. Random noise has no input property at all. Check your sources.

Answer (score 5):

This is a fun little problem, you can solve it with this sort of algorithm:

1. generate a small uniform noise
2. resample it to a higher resolution (giving you a smooth noise image)
3. Apply threshold to get a False/True array
4. Map False/True to '-'/'#'

And with a bit of printing formatting it works well. Demonstration:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import zoom
arr = np.random.uniform(size=(4,4))
arr = zoom(arr, 8)
arr = arr > 0.5
arr = np.where(arr, '-', '#')
arr = np.array_str(arr, max_line_width=500)
print(arr)
```

output:

```
[['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#']
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#']
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#']
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#']
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#']
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#']
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#']
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#']
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#']
 ['-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#']
 ['#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#']
 ['#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#']
 ['#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#']
 ['#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#']
 ['#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '#' '#' '#']
 ['#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['#' '#' '#' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']]
```

Of course a Perlin or Simplex noise like other answerers indicated would give a slightly better look. If you want to try that, replace steps 1 and 2 with Perlin/Simplex or any other noise you can grab and try again.

Comment: `raise ValueError("threshold must be non-NAN` removing this line uncrashes program, but only parts of array are shown

Comment: @reducingactivity not sure I follow, what do you mean ?

Comment: `np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)` crashes with `raise ValueError("threshold must be non-NAN ...`

Comment: It looks like they've changed the signature, can you try with `np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)` ?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html

Comment: `NameError: name 'sys' is not defined` - and adding also `import sys` on top brings it to life! It also fixes truncated lines.

Answer (score 3):

Rather use cellular automatons. The algorithm that you find [here](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Cellular_Automata_Method_for_Generating_Random_Cave-Like_Levels) creates similar patterns that you you would like to see:

```
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . # # . . . . . # . .
. . . . # # # # . . . # # # .
. . . . . # # # # . . # # # .
. . . . . . # # # # # # # . .
. . . . . . # # # # # # # . .
. . . . # # # # # # # # # . .
. . . # # # # # # # # # # . .
. . # # # # # # . # . # # . .
. . # # # # # . . # . . . . .
. . . # # # # . . . # # # . .
. . . # # # # . . . # # # # .
. . # # # # . . . . . # # # .
. . # # # # . . . . . # # . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```